# how to use spring data mongodb repository query annotation for updating

Tags: mongodb, annotations, repository, spring-data

I am using mongodb for a java application and trying to use spring data repository to update the document. I use the @Query annotation like this:
@Query("{ 'username' : ?0 }, { $set : { 'age' : ?1}}")
void updateAgeByUserName(String username, int age);

But this doesn't work. I know the save will update the whole thing but I just want to update the age field using update query. How can I do this?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring-data is a framework for general purpose that provides a very basic support to CRUD operations. If you need *complex* operations, like update using any `$operator`, you'll need to implement a [custom repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) to it.

Comment: Note that there is an open ticket to Spring Data MongoDB to add this functionality. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1253. Unfortunately this issue is a few years old and has not had recent activity.